# Form a JSON get an multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, json

I receive a json like this:

```
[{"name":"banana","country":"Algeria"},{"name":"Apple","country":"China"}]
```

How can I transform this to an array, where the key would be the `name` ?

I'm using `json_decode($json, true);` but it creates an auto incremental keys.

So I would like something like this:

```
Array
(
    [banana] => Array
        (
            [country] => Algeria
        )
    [Apple] => Array
        (
            [country] => China
        )
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: simple way is array_combine with array_column, https://3v4l.org/sHsT1 if you dont mind leaving in name (though you could remove it with array_map, https://3v4l.org/T0LfL), or you could simply use a foreach, few ways, you should at least try one before asking

Comment: using a `foreach()`, one [way](https://3v4l.org/G6ZCC)

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

json code:

```
{
    "Banana": {
        "country":"Algeria"
    },
    "Apple": {
        "country":"China"
    }
}
```

php code:

```
    <?php
        $fruitsandcountries = json_decode(file_get_contents("filename.json"), true);
        echo($fruitsandcountries['Banana']['country']);
    ?>
```

output:

Algeria